# Use jQuery Select2 with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use Select2 in Razor in ASP.NET MVC. But I can't get work.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".genreOptions").select2({
                tags: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: 'http://localhost:65148/NewProfile/Genres',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            q: params.term, // search term
                            page: params.page
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data, page) {
                        var newData = [];
                        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                            newData.push({
                                id: item.Id,  //id part present in data 
                                text: item.Genre  //string to be displayed
                            });
                        });
                        return { results: newData };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
                minimumInputLength: 1
            });

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BandProfile.Genres, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class="genreOptions", multiple = "multiple", style ="width: 100%;"} )
```

The searching for tags works fine. But when I post the form, the count of the input field Is 0. How can I capture the data from the input form?

Answer (score 1):

@Bryan I build up a javascript array and pass it with ajax to the server. Seems to work ok for my purposes. Perhaps you could try that. The selectors I put below will be different than what you need but here is the general idea...

On Click

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {

      fillHiddenInput();

      var dataToSend = $('#hiddenInput').val();

      //Submit the form with ajax or however you want to get dataToSend to server
});
```

FillHiddenInput function...

```
var fillHiddenInput = function () {

      $('#hiddenInput').val("");
      var stuff = [];

      $('.ms-selection .ms-list li ul').children('li').each(function (){

          if ($(this).hasClass('ms-selected')) 
           {
              stuff.push($(this).children('span').text());
           }

      });

    $('#hiddenInput').val(stuff);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do that. I want to use razor here.